# Ubuntu 22.04. How to add repo in sources.list using add-apt-repository?

Tags: repository, 22.04, add-apt-repository

System is clear and only installed and updated.
The problem is:
I clean /etc/apt/sources.list

```
:>/etc/apt/sources.list
```

When try to add repo:

```
add-apt-repository -s "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main restricted"
```

or

```
add-apt-repository -s "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted"
```

I have added in sources.list.d, but not in sources.list.

```
    root@testu22:~# add-apt-repository -s "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main restricted"
Repository: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy restricted main'
Description:
Archive for codename: jammy components: restricted,main
More info: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Adding deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Reading package lists... Done
```

sources.list after add-apt-repository:

```
root@testu22:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
```

And **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_jammy.list** is empty

second run

```
root@testu22:~# add-apt-repository -s "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted"
Repository: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted'
Description:
Archive for codename: jammy components: main,restricted
More info: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.^[[A
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Adding deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted Sources [23,7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main Sources [1 340 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [1 040 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1 395 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [510 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [423 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [100,0 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [148 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15,8 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [30,3 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [129 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30,4 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted Translation-en [18,6 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [488 B]
Fetched 5 475 kB in 3s (1 733 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
```

After that:

```
root@testu22:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
```

**Is it possible to add repo in *sources.list*?**

**UPDATE:**
As I see problem is in empty sources.list. If add for example empty line or # for size wasn't 0b in sources.list. The problem partially is fixed, but now All deb source in sources.list and deb-src in sources.list.d

**Solution for resolve**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# clear sources.list but shouldn't be empty
echo " " > /etc/apt/sources.list

# adding repos to sources.lis.d folder
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main restricted universe multiverse"
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc)-updates main restricted universe multiverse"
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc)-backports main restricted universe multiverse"
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-security main restricted universe multiverse"

# The second run for System indentify it as template:
### Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list
### Archive has template, updating /etc/apt/sources.list
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main restricted universe multiverse"
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc)-updates main restricted universe multiverse"
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc)-backports main restricted universe multiverse"
add-apt-repository -n -y "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-security main restricted universe multiverse"

# All commented deb-src repo stay in sources.list.d and all deb repo will be in sources.list

apt update
```

Comment: What is the second set of scans for?  I don't see what they are going to accomplish.

Comment: Explain:
First add repo wil add it to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list`
But I need it in `/etc/apt/sources.list` directly. If run add-apt-repository again it will read existing repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list` and identify it as template and add to /etc/apt/sources.list and remove from `etc/apt//sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-jammy.list` . I don't know why it doesn't add it from on first run. So, I need to run it twice.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. Looking at the Ubuntu wiki, there is no command line option to change where it goes. However you can still do

```
    echo “deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/jammy main restricted” >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And that will add the line to /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I know about this workaround... But now need to rewrite scripts for deploy config systems in my company :(
And I need to change script for update from 18 and 20 Ubuntu. We have some custom config and cant use system upgrade clearly
But Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oh ok. If it works you could modify the source code for apt and get your own apt-add-repository